# String comparison in TS is failing while using "Includes" method

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I am trying to solve this trivial Typescript string comparison issue. I am using the JS mocha framework and validating actual vs. expected results. For the expected result I am collecting it from the JSON file (resource file), whereas for actual result getting it from UI. While debugging, I could see the actual string contains the expected result but my test is always failing. Below, I have provided the actual and expected strings. Can anyone please provide some pointers on this?

Actual:

```
prints_explore_products_header prints_project_history_list_item Vertical scroll bar, 1 page Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page prints_prints_home_open_projects prints_view_category_card Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page Vertical scroll bar, 1 page Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page Vertical scroll bar, 2 pages _prints_header_photos_logo prints_url_navigation_exit Choose a Tabletop Décor option prints_view_product_B07QBVL9RZ prints_view_product Vertical scroll bar, 1 page Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page prints_header_photos_logo prints_url_navigation_exit Custom Metal Tabletop Vertical scroll bar, 1 page Size: 4x4 prints_product_size_4x4 prints_product_size_5x5 Vertical scroll bar, 2 pages Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page Price: $18.99 Usually ships within 3 to 5 days. Ships from and sold by Harman.com. prints_product_detail_get_started About this item Description Aluminum panel with stylish wooden base. Features & details • Sleek 4"x4" metal panel • Print your favorite photo on a thin, aluminum panel for a glossy, metallic look. • Colors pop, with crisp whites and deep blacks, and the surface is scratch- and fade-resistant. • Metal panel easily slides into a wooden base for displaying • Customize and complete your order in minutes using our intuitive online tool. Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page Vertical scroll bar, 2 pages prints_header_photos_logo prints_url_navigation_exit
```

Expected: "Aluminum panel with stylish wooden base."

Result:

> Exception : Description message is not displaying as expected

Code:

```js
  VerifyDetailPageContentsNew(ProductDetail:any,productSubCategory:string):boolean {
        
        expect(PrintsProductDetailPageObj.verifyProductDescriptionAndDetails(ProductDetail,productSubCategory)).toBeTruthy;
        
    }
verifyProductDescriptionAndDetails(productDetails:any, productSubcategory:string) : boolean
    {
       
        let actualDescription:string = this.getDeliveryMsg(productDetails.description).getText();
        let expectedDescription:string = <string>productDetails.description;

        console.log("Actual description:"+ actualDescription);
        console.log("Expected Description :" + expectedDescription);
        if(actualDescription.includes(`${productDetails.description}`)) {
            console.log("Got description");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw "Failed: Description message is not displaying as expected";
        }
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to tell the cause as we don't know what `getDeliveryMsg` does and `getText`. You should consider rewriting all of code though.

Comment: GetText() is inbuilt method from WDIO. I don't think that will help, but I am adding my wrapper methods getDeliveryMsg() for your reference. Let me know if you need anything. Thanks in advance.      getDeliveryMsg(deliveryMsg:string):any{
        return  driver.isIOS ?$( `-ios predicate string: name CONTAINS ${deliveryMsg}`)
        : $(`android=new UiSelector().className("android.widget.TextView").textContains(${deliveryMsg})`)
    }